# How do I turn on this water valve?

Tags: water, washing-machine, hose

I just got a new washer and dryer and this valve got turned during installation. I cannot turn the red one to be on, it is stuck. I would be welcome to any tips on fixing this.
[image]

Comment: Whatever you do, turn off the hot water before you force anything. If your struggles end up breaking the valve, you don't want hot water shooting everywhere while you run to find a shutoff valve.

Comment: Spray some vinegar or similar onto it.  Then try turning it it again.  The spots on the valve might be from hard water.  You might need to take the handle off to let the vinegar soak into the valve.

Comment: On top of the other tips, sometimes these are just hard to turn. What ever you do, dont use a hammer.

Comment: Google Ball Valve Stuck

Answer (score 0):

Based on the position of the cold water valve, turn the hot valve counter clockwise 1/4 turn. In other words, turn the tab projecting on the left towards the washing machine.

Put a Crescent wrench on the right side of the handle and push toward the wall to start the valve turning. Ot you could use channel locks pliers on the right side.

If you only can turn it 1/8 turn by wrenching on the right side, then switch to the left side to complete the 90 deg turn CCW.

Comment: I'd put a big channel-lok on the valve itself (to keep it from moving) before trying to turn the red handle, just to make sure the valve itself doesn't rotate on the pipe or break off the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the red top, then wrap it in a vinegar soaked cloth and let it sit at least overnight. Dampen it once or twice if you think of it. You have a blue valve which is identical so turn that off and on so you know which way to turn the red one. If you use more them hand force turn the water off to save yourself time cleaning up and possibly getting burned.